# How to redirect the Apache log in Kubernetes

Tags: apache, kubernetes, containers

I am having one namespace and one deployment(replica set), My Apache logs should be written outside the pod, how is it possible in Kubernetes.

Comment: This isn't the sort of programming question that's generally on-topic for Stack Overflow; the [help/on-topic] describes what's allowable here.  In the Kubernetes documentation, [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) describes some basic patterns with sample setups.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

You should specify more precisely what you exactly mean by *outside the pod*, but as [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) have already suggested in his comment, take a closer look at [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) section in the official **kubernetes documentation**.

Depending on what you mean by *"outside the Pod"*, different solution may be the most optimal in your case.

As you can read there:

> *Kubernetes provides no native storage solution for log data, but you can integrate many existing logging solutions into your Kubernetes
> cluster ... Cluster-level logging architectures are described in assumption that a logging backend is present inside or outside of your cluster.*

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures) are mentioned 3 most popular cluster-level logging architectures:

> - Use a node-level logging agent that runs on every node.
> - Include a dedicated sidecar container for logging in an application pod.
> - Push logs directly to a backend from within an application.

Second solution is widely used. Unlike the third one where the logs pushing needs to be handled by your application container, [sidecar approach](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-sidecar-container-with-the-logging-agent) is application independend, which makes it much more flexible solution.

So that the matter was not so simple, it can be implemented in two different ways:

- [Streaming sidecar container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container)
- [Sidecar container with a logging agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-a-logging-agent)

Comment: Thanks for your response, we are using the Kubernetes on-premises, I don't want to load my pod with Apache and tomcat logs(access.log,erro.log,Catalina.log), we can mount the location(on physical server) and  it is possible to move the logs from pod to mount location?
 or we need to depend on the third party tools?( fluent bit,elastic-search, kibana)

Comment: I would recommend using third-party tools as kubernetes doesn't provide a mean of exporting the logs to an external location. If you mount the location for logs on your kubernetes nodes e.g. some nfs share, theoretically you can also create a custom script which may run as cron job and will periodically move logs from your kubernetes node to that location, but I would rather rely on a third-party solution than using some custom scripts.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help, Now we are using the custom's script to move the logs.